# Best approach to finding a statistical significance within the data

Tags: anova, pca, manova

$\textbf{Description of Dataset:}$

I've got a dataset where 3 mice per cage are fed a certain diet. There are 3 diets and a control diet (4 diets all up), and 3 cages tied to each diet, so 36 observations. Their microbial data (or microbes) are recorded and there are 42 variables/columns of data. Since I'm no biology student I don't know if the variables are independent or dependent of each other.

$\textbf{Question:}$

I've been given the task to find any association between the diet and microbials. I'm not too sure what the best statistical test or approach is to find anything significant within the data (if the diets affect microbes or not). My first impression was to do PCA, however, the first 2 components account for only 48% of variance and its not until the 10th component is 90% accounted for. I'm now thinking performing an ANOVA on all 42 variables is the best approach. Could I also potentially do MANOVA. Are there any other models or approaches that will be much more efficient and/or accurate? Maybe even a t-test between the diets within a variable.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This seems like a good way to discover false patterns, overestimate differences, and get the wrong signs of differences. To do this properly requires you to use some kind of adjustment for multiple comparisons, but you have enough comparisons that I would expect the typical techniques to sap away your power to detect and accurately estimate differences. “Hey, statistician, go figure out something cool in the data,” is usually a bad idea.